# loading php file + get varible + ajax reload

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a php file that works well on the following link:
http://localhost/results.php?uid=1

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error());

$logged_in_user = $_GET['uid'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM oc2_users WHERE id_user = $logged_in_user";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $results = $row['points'];
}

echo $results;
?>
```

I want to have this file on an other page and want it to reload every second. With the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>


    function refresh_div() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url:'http://localhost/results.php?uid=1',
            type:'POST',
            success:function(results) {
                jQuery(".result").html(results);
            }
        });
    }

    t = setInterval(refresh_div,1000);
</script>
```

When I load this 2nd page it returns: "Undefined index: uid".
Where am I going wrong with this? How can I make sure that the variable goes through as well? Thanks

Comment: In the `t = setInterval(refresh_div,1000);`, since you are calling a function, shouldn't be there the parenthesis, like `t = setInterval(refresh_div(),1000);`?

Comment: My comment doesn't resolve the problem, but your code is vulnerable for sql-injection. Imagine what happens when uri will be `http://localhost/results.php?uid=1 or user_id=10 desc` or even like this `?uid=1; create table hacked (id integer, ts integer);`

Comment: The script works fine if i dont have variable in it.

Comment: Like this? `setTimeout(function () {
    refresh_div();
}, 1000);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your aswers. You helped a lot.
The solution: is what @Kanudo suggested but it only works with POST. You can find below the code that works:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error());

$logged_in_user = $_POST["uid"];

$query = "SELECT * FROM oc2_users WHERE id_user = $logged_in_user";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $results = $row['points'];
}

echo $results;

?>
```

and the jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>


    function refresh_div() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url:'http://localhost/results.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {uid: 1},
            success:function(results) {
                jQuery(".result").html(results);
            }
        });
    }

    t = setInterval(refresh_div,1000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your AJAX request is by POST method and your PHP accepts GET request
Just need to correct the same. You can use Either but both PHP & requesting AJAX should have the SAME.

**jQuery part**

```
$(function () {

    $.ajax({

        url: "http://localhost/results.php",
        data:  {uid: 1},
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) { console.log(data); }

    });
});
```

**PHP Part**

```
<?php

    if (isset($_GET['uid']))
    {
        echo 'This is the UID = ' . $_GET['uid'];
    }

?>
```

Comment: Nice try. But having the same problem.

Comment: I updated the answer try it and inform about the result that is displayed in the console

Comment: Still the same message.

Comment: `data: {uid: 1}` - comma missed at the end of line

Comment: @SzabóTamás have a look at the updated answer. Check it

Comment: result is a blank page.

Comment: did you seen the console?

Comment: @szabo-tamas blank page? means not getting response? Did u checked console for errors